# What's the future of std::valarray look like?

Tags: c++, c++11, numerics

Up until fairly recently I hadn't been keeping up with the C++11 deliberations.  As I try to become more familiar with it and the issues being worked, I came across [this site](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) which seems to be advocating for deprecating or removing `std::valarray` since most people are using [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) instead.  I guess I'm probably one of the few people out there who still uses `std::valarray` (and yes I know the class has a sordid past, a tarnished present, and a questionable future).  But, it does what I need, and perhaps more important, it's part of the standard (for now any way).

Aside from the one site above, I've been able to find very little on what is actually happening with `std::valarray` in the new standard, and was hoping that somebody on SO might be able to provide some insight and / or references where [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1T4ADRA_enUS350US350&q=c%2B%2B0x%20valarray&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) and even the [C++ Standards Committee Web Site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) have so far failed me.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to migrate from valarry to anything else (not that there seems to be any particular reason for you to if you're happy with it), take a look at Eigen as an alternative to Blitz.  http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`std::valarray` is included in C++11.  It has not been deprecated or removed.  It has been updated to include move operations

`std::valarray` is defined in §26.6[numarray] of the C++11 language standard.

Comment: @James, Great!  That's what I was looking for.