# How to compare C++ slice_array? Why it cannot be compared as valarray?

Tags: c++, stl, valarray

I wonder why I cannot compare `some_valarray[first_slice] < another_valarray[second_slice]` as I compare `some_valarray < another_valarray` and how I can do that in simple way without copying? Of course, I can iterate over them in plain loop but, maybe, there is more elegant and, probably, optimizable way?

Comment: As far as I can recall, `valarray` is deprecated.

Comment: @Lingxi could you please provide some proof of that? Tried to google for it but haven't found anything that makes sense.

Comment: Seems I were wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576688/whats-the-future-of-stdvalarray-look-like

Comment: @Lingxi yep, I read that too.

Answer (score 2):

To compare a [slice_array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice) you currently have to use [valarray( const std::slice_array& )](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/valarray).

```
#include <valarray>

int main() {
  //Initialize valarray
  std::valarray<int> val0{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::valarray<int> val1{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

  //Compare valarray
  std::valarray<bool> cmp0 = val0 < val1;

  //Compare slice_array
  std::valarray<bool> cmp1 = 
std::valarray<int>(val0[std::slice(0,5,2)]) < std::valarray<int>(val1[std::slice(1,5,2)]);

  //Compare slice_array since c++17
  std::valarray<bool> cmp2 =
std::valarray(val0[std::slice(0,5,2)]) < std::valarray(val1[std::slice(1,5,2)]);

  return 0;
}
```